# win32com COM method call returning name of object's type instead of object

Tags: python, win32com

My company has an internal C# library that I'm trying to call from CPython 2.7 using win32com. We have an object which I'll call Type1, which is in a C# namespace that I'll call Company.System.SubSystem1. One particular method of this object (let's call it GetCurrentType2Object) returns an object of type Company.System.SubSystem2.Type2. The code I have is as follows:

```
import win32com.client
type1_object = win32com.client.Dispatch("Company.System.SubSystem1.Type1")
type2_object = type1_object.GetCurrentType2Object()
```

The problem is that type2_object does not get assigned a Type2 object; it gets the string "Company.System.SubSystem2.Type2".

There are other methods on the same object that return void, integers, or enum values, and those all appear to succeed. There is no other method that returns a class type for me to try, this is the only one.

I've tried using the makepy.py script on the library in question before running my code, and it has its own problems before even getting this far; the generated file seems to contain a small subset of the actual interface, which does not include many of the methods I need. The Microsoft COM object viewer shows the same subset, so I can't blame this on the script, and I gave up trying to figure it out.

I'm aware of IronPython, and I may very well end up just using it instead, since that would be a much less roundabout way of working with .NET code, but I would really like to understand what's happening here before I make any decisions, and just to satisfy my own curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

It appears what may be happening is that win32com.client.dynamic is deciding that the method I'm trying to call is actually a property, and so the method doesn't get invoked correctly. I'm not certain because I don't really understand how that decision is made, but I was able to work around the problem by forcing a method to be generated instead of a property. You can do that by calling win32com's _FlagAsMethod. For the example in the question, that would look like:

```
type1_object._FlagAsMethod("GetCurrentType2Object")
```

Do that before trying to call GetCurrentType2Object and everything works fine.